# JS / HTML Adding params to a given filelist for a file upload

Tags: javascript, form-data, filelist

For a file upload I collect multiple files :

```
<input type="file" multiple onchange="uploadFiles(this)" id="fd" />
```

In the JS function `uploadFiles()` I retrieve each file and append it to a `formData` object :

```
function uploadFiles(e)  {
  var fileList = document.getElementById(e.id).files;

  var fd = new FormData();
  for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
    var file = fileList[i];
    fd.append('files[]', file, file.name);
  }
}
```

Finally I upload it via AJAX to a server.

Each file object contains 4 key/value parameter with the key: name, LastModified, webkitRelativePath and size.

On the server side I need additional information per file (description from a user) which I want to send with the same upload process. My question is :

Is it possible to add params to the `file` object so I can retrieve them which each file on the server side ?

If not, how to bind additional parameters to each appended `file` object in the `FormData` object ?

Any hints are welcome. Info: I use pure JS only.